# Android load ListView in background using cursor adapter

Tags: java, android

I want to load data into listview with cursor adapter using background thread any help
I have googled a lot but can not find any helping material. I am using this scenario to avoid thread stuck. it is working fine on main thread but I just need in the background. I have Implemented async task but all in vain

```
class HeavyWorker extends AsyncTask < Cursor , Context , Void > {

    private ProgressDialog      progressDialog ;
    private Context             targetCtx ;

    public HeavyWorker ( Context context ) {
        this.targetCtx = context ;

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog ( targetCtx ) ;
        progressDialog.setCancelable ( false ) ;
        progressDialog.setMessage ( "Retrieving data..." ) ;
        progressDialog.setTitle ( "Please wait" ) ;
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate ( true ) ;
    }

    @ Override
    protected void onPreExecute ( ) {
        progressDialog.show ( ) ;
    }

    @ Override
    protected Void doInBackground ( Cursor ... params ) {
        final ComplexGridViewColumnAdapter adapter = new ComplexGridViewColumnAdapter(context, cursor, true);
        Toast.makeText(context, "" + cursor.getCount() + " Records found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        listView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        adapter.setListener(getContext(), NewComplexGridColumnView.this, currentQuestion.isHasHitoricalData(), currentQuestion.isSkuSelectionEnabled());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
       return null ;
    }

    @ Override
    protected void onPostExecute ( Void result ) {
        if(progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()){
            progressDialog.dismiss ( ) ;
        }
    }
```

this is my async task class

Comment: add what have you done so for.

Comment: Your async task does nothing. It just returns null...

Comment: it is just example

Comment: Do not access UI from non-UI thread.

Comment: @YuriiTsap what do you mean I can not understand

Comment: @NisarAhmad doInBackground is performed on internal executor inside of the AsyncTask, which means you are doing operations related to UI thread on non-UI thread. This shouldn't happen even if you are just changing the visibility or making toast.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `Loaders`. It's quite easy I won't attach code samples as you can find them by yourself.
Here are some links :

- [Official docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)
- [Grokking android](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/using-loaders-in-android/)
- [The easiest one](http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/60331340133/very-simple-example-of-a-loader-and-loadermanager)

Answer (score 0):

Updating UI Elements inside doInBackground() is not a good practice.

you can get the results in doInBackground() and call a listener method.

Something like this :

```
 @ Override
protected Void doInBackground ( Cursor ... params ) {
    final ComplexGridViewColumnAdapter adapter = new ComplexGridViewColumnAdapter(context, cursor, true);
    Toast.makeText(context, "" + cursor.getCount() + " Records found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    listener.updateListView(cursor);
   return null ;
}
```